# How can i toggle htis link to show a span

Tags: jquery, toggle

Looking at the below I would like to show the span element
   when i click the button  on each row and also hide when i click it again.
So i need to have 2 buttons one that expands and the other collpses 
The below kind of works but only in IE not in firefox.
How can i loop through each button in the tr
Thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("button").click(function () {


             var a = $(this).text();
             var b = ".s" + a + "";
             $(b).slideDown();
         });
     });
 </script>


<tr>
      <td> <button>Toggle5</button>
            <br>
            <span class="sToggle5" style="display: none;">New</span>
            </td>

            </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
      <td> <button>Toggle6</button>
            <br>
            <span class="sToggle6" style="display: none;">New</span>
            </td>

            </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Than make use of `.slideToggle()` function for hide and show...available in jquery library

check out : [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) - : Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

Answer (score 0):

cant you just use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead of `slideDown`? and you really dont need the `+ ""` on your b variable

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too hard for yourself.

Exchange this:

```
$("button").click(function () {


     var a = $(this).text();
     var b = ".s" + a + "";
     $(b).slideDown();
 });
```

With this:

```
$("button").click(function() { 
    $(this).siblings("span").slideToggle();
});
```

Done. The button will now slide the span open if it's closed, or closed if it's open. And since it's a sibling, you don't need to dodder about with class names and whatnot.

Comment: thanks guys as you can see i had to come up with some id's on the fly as i'm using it in a listview(asp.net).
when i use slideToggle it doesn't work well in Firefox but it does with IE.
How can i use up down images with the toggle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(<span class here>).slideToggle('slow');
```